# Write an update statement with a join for ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to make work the following oracle SQL statement:

```
update task  
set t.dtdue = add_months(p.dtapplication,48)
from task t
inner join ptoprocedure p on p.idproc = t.idproc
where t.idprocess = 1017 and t.idactivity = 6
```

it does not seem to work and i was wondering if the syntax i'm using only works for SQL server.
I found that for Oracle, it's required to use a select statement inside the update but i can't figure it out.
Thank you for your help

I tried to use a select statement inside the update

Comment: What's the cardinality of the join? Can it produce more than one `ptoprocedure` per `task`?

Comment: "it does not seem to work..." -- What's the error?

Comment: @TheImpaler . No, it can't. The error is : "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: Please indicate the cardinality. What do you want to happen when there are no matches?

Answer (score 2):

You could rephrase this as an update using a correlated subquery:

```sql
UPDATE task t  
SET dtdue = (SELECT ADD_MONTHS(p.dtapplication, 48)
             FROM ptoprocedure p
             WHERE p.idproc = t.idproc)
WHERE t.idprocess = 1017 AND t.idactivity = 6;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your query is more aligned with SQL Server rather than Oracle. In Oracle, you can use a correlated subquery.you can do as below ,

```
UPDATE task t
SET t.dtdue = (
  SELECT add_months(p.dtapplication, 48)
  FROM ptoprocedure p
  WHERE p.idproc = t.idproc
)
WHERE t.idprocess = 1017 
AND t.idactivity = 6
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM ptoprocedure p 
  WHERE p.idproc = t.idproc
);
```

This will update the `dtdue` column in the task table by adding 48 months to the dtapplication from the ptoprocedure table, for rows where `idprocess = 1017` and `idactivity = 6`.

The EXISTS clause is used to prevent updating rows in task table when there is no corresponding `idproc` in `ptoprocedure` table. Without this clause, the `dtdue` field would be set to `NULL` if the subquery returns no rows.

Answer (score 2):

If p.idproc is unique (that is, if it is a unique or primary key or there is a unique index on it, or if you are using Oracle 21c or later which does not require one) then you can do it this way:

```
update (
    select t.dtdue, p.dtapplication
    from   task t join ptoprocedure p on p.idproc = t.idproc
    where  t.idprocess = 1017 and t.idactivity = 6
)
set dtdue = add_months(dtapplication,48)
```

or perhaps if you prefer

```
update (
    select t.dtdue, add_months(dtapplication,48) as new_date
    from   task t join ptoprocedure p on t.idproc = p.idproc
    where  t.idprocess = 1017 and t.idactivity = 6
)
set dtdue = new_date
```